# jQuery - Wrapping a dynamically loaded image

Tags: jquery

I am trying to wrap a dynamically loaded image with a link tag:

```
        var img = new Image();
        slideData[slide].imgData = img; 
        $(img).load(function () {
            $(this).css('display','none');
            $(this).wrap("<a></a>");
            slidesLoaded++;
        }).attr({src:mediaURL+slideData[slide].image, alt:slideData[slide].title});
```

This doesn't seem to work? When I do this:

```
$(slideData[0].imgData).appendTo('body').fadeIn()
```

There are no a tags, just the image.

Is this possible?

Comment: When does this script execute?  On `.ready()`?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you stored the `<img>` element in `slideData[slide].imgData`, not the wrapper `<a>` element. Try:

```
$(slideData[0].imgData.parentNode).appendTo('body').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap an element, that doesn't change the elements you have in your jQuery set.

Also, when you insert an element somewhere in the document (using `.append`, `.prepend`, etc), then that **removes** the element from its current position and puts it where you said.

So what's happening is that you're putting your image inside an `<a>` tag and then immediately removing it again to put it in the body. The `<a>` tag is never appended to the body. Obviously, the solution is to append the `<a>` instead of the image.

```
$(img).load(function () {
    $("<a></a>")
        .append($(this).hide())
        .appendTo(document.body);
});
```