# jQuery - Wrapping a Link on a Image

Tags: jquery

I am trying to wrap a image with a link but I am having trouble doing so.

```
            $j('<img />', {
                    'src': 'imageSrc.jpg',
                    'style': 'display:none;',
                    'id': 'image'
                    })
                    .appendTo('#imageWrapper');
```

I have tried using .after, .before, and .wrap but the links are not coming up or they are not wrapping around the image.

I have looked at [Hanpan's problem and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788275/jquery-wrapping-a-dynamically-loaded-image) but the solution doesn't fit mine.

Should I change my code to fit like his or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap an element with [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Xq9YQ/) which may be of assistance too.

Comment: How odd.... now it is working. Seems like I just had to make it "<a>" instead of "<a></a>"